# How to call string function in any class of javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have this function which is to upload an images.

```
    MyImages.instance.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {

        // support
        if ($.inArray(file.type, ['image/png','image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/gif']) != -1) {

            var storage = firebase.storage();
            var storageRef = storage.ref('' + file.name);
            var uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);
            uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
            }, function(error) {
            console.log('Error Uploaded');
            }, function() {
            var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
            console.log('Uploaded a blob or file! ' + downloadURL);
            });
            var getImageUrl = function(file){
                var returnVal;
            storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
                returnVal = url;
            });
                return returnVal;
            };
            console.log('return value ' + getImageUrl);
            formData.append('image', file);
        }

    });
```

and then i created this function to know if the images was upload successfully

```
MyImages.instance.on('success', function(file, response) {

    //support
    if (response.data && response.data.link) {

        if (response.status != 200 && response.data.error) {
            MyImages.notification(response.data.error);
        }

        file.external_link = response.data.link;

        // Add the message to the textarea
        MyImages.text.add('[img]' + file.external_link + '[/img]');
        console.log(file.external_link);
        if (response.data.deletehash) {
            file.deletehash = response.data.deletehash;
        }

        MyImages.notification(MyImages.lang.uploaded_to_firebase);

        return;

    }

});
```

I'm using dropzone.js, what I want to ask is how to get this code

```
file.external_link
```

is the same as

```
returnVal
```

or how to use **returnVal** in other function, so it will be able to use again and again

Answer (score 0):

To work on with "file.external_link" you best use a callback inside the function for the "success".

e.g.

```
MyImages.instance.on('success', function(file, response) {

    //...
    // when your function is in this context
    this.handeFilePath(file.external_link);

    return;

}.bind(this)); // add this context to function scope to call handeFilePath()
```

Or even better handle all the success handling in a custom callback.
e.g.

```
MyImages.instance.on('success', handeFilePathOrSomethingOther);

var handeFilePathOrSomethingOther = function(file, response) {
    // your stuff           
};
```

Comment: looks like I have to use firebase usage first before work on file.external_link